# Funky indentation in SML mode

Tags: emacs, indentation, sml

I installed SML Mode in Emacs and the indentation is messed up. I disabled all my .emacs customizations, but that didn't make any difference. At the end of each line in the code below, I used `C-j`, which is mapped to `newline-and-indent`.

[image: pow]

[image: dist]

If I highlight everything and reindent (`C-M-\`), the result makes more sense:

[image: pow-improved]
[image: dist-improved]

I'm using Emacs 24.1.1 and SML Mode 6.2 on Ubuntu 12.10. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `newline-and-indent`.
You can use `reindent-then-new-and-indent` or `electric-indent-mode` instead.

Comment: Interesting. When I use those commands, the wacky indentation still appears in the line I'm currently editing, but after I hit Enter, the line is shunted leftward to where it should be. Is this how it's supposed to work? Regardless, it's a great improvement over what had been happening.

Comment: Yes, that's the way it's supposed to work: Emacs does not usually reindent "in the background".  It only reindents when you ask it to.  This is normally done with TAB, but can be piggybacked on other keys, such as RET, so until you hit one of those keys, the line just keeps the indentation it had.  In your case, the line starts with the "wrong" indentation because the SML mode can't know what you're about to type, and it just happens to presume you'll be typing some further argument (oblivious to the fact that 0 and 1 can't be functions).

Answer (score 0):

try in the .emacs file:

```
(setq default-tab-width 4); 
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil);
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command);
```

I'm no wizard but that worked for me.
http://www.pement.org/emacs_tabs.htm

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Stefan's (now 4 year old...) suggestion, you can auto-enable the minor mode `electric-indent-mode` for `sml-mode` by putting this:

```
  (push (lambda () electric-indent-local-mode 1) sml-mode-hook)
```

somewhere in your emacs initialization code.

Or, you might prefer:

```
(use-package sml-mode
   :config
   (push (lambda () electric-indent-local-mode 1) sml-mode-hook))
```

This seems to me to produce reasonably sane behavior for indenting code in `sml-mode`.